# SwiftUI - ScrollView Navigation issues

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, scrollview

SwiftUI: 5.9
XCode: 15.0.1
iPhone 11
iOS: 17.0.3

I am building an app with couple of screens. In one of the View I try to implement Vertical ScrollView with cca 3 - 6 Horizontal ScrollViews. They will display Thumbnails, Click on them should navigate to other screen/view (Camera). This works ok only first time I get to this screen. Once I am in Camera View and I hit button back, I get navigated to the first screen, but then the app freezes and there's nothing I can do. There are no errors displayed, the app freezes and there's nothing I can do. I read somewhere that there are bugs when navigating from scroll views in Swift, but I need to find a solution. This is the code:

```
struct Home2View: View {

@StateObject var accountViewModel: AccountViewModel
@StateObject var myPozeGroupViewModel: MyPozeGroupViewModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack (spacing: 50) {
    
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    horizontalList(data: myPozeGroupViewModel.top10MyPozeGroups, backgroundColor: .green)
                    }

                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        horizontalList(data: myPozeGroupViewModel.freshest10MyPozeGroups)
                    }
            
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        horizontalList(data: myPozeGroupViewModel.letters10MyPozeGroups)
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            if myPozeGroupViewModel.top10MyPozeGroups.isEmpty {
                myPozeGroupViewModel.addListenerForTop10()
            }
            
            if myPozeGroupViewModel.freshest10MyPozeGroups.isEmpty {
                myPozeGroupViewModel.addListenerForFreshest10()
            }
            
            if myPozeGroupViewModel.letters10MyPozeGroups.isEmpty {
                myPozeGroupViewModel.addListenerForLetters10()
            }
        }
    }
}

func horizontalList(data: [MyPozeGroup], backgroundColor: Color = .blue) -> some View {
    HStack(spacing:5) {
        ForEach(data) { myPozeGroup in
            NavigationLink(destination: CameraView(
                myPozeGroup: myPozeGroup,
                myPozeGroupViewModel: myPozeGroupViewModel,
                accountViewModel: accountViewModel)
            ) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: myPozeGroup.thumbnail ?? "")) { image in
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(height: 20)
                        .overlay(
                            HStack {
                                Text(myPozeGroup.name ?? "")
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("\(myPozeGroup.counter)")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        )
                }
                .cornerRadius(20)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

If someone can help and explain what can I do to overcome the issue would be great.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It is suspicious that you are not initialising your `@StateObject`s. If they are passed from the superview, they should be `@ObservedObject`s.

Comment: I am using StateObjects throughout the app for accessing values from ObservableObjects and that does seem to work ok.  Did However try the variant here with @ObseredObject, but that did not help. There's an issue with  NavigationView - ScrollView - ForEach - NavigationLink . . .

Comment: One step to the right direction is that I should be using .navigationDestination modifier. I did try that and works ok in simple example.  However, when I try to apply logic to my app's, there's still the case that all Views in navigationDestination gets initialized before clicking on single one...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I found the reason. I had some ML models running at the background and for some weird reason I had a code that was supposedly stopping AVSession from main thread, while that was starting at main. Still weird I had no messages before freeze.